# How to get the values for a series of checkboxes in Laravel 4 controller (if checked)

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to get the values for a series of checkboxes I have set up in a Laravel 4 form.  Here is the code in the view setting up the checkboxes:

```
@foreach ($friends as $friend)
<input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="friend[]" id="{{$friend}}" value="{{$friend}}">
@endforeach
```

In my controller, I would like to get the values for the checked boxes and put them in an array.  I am not exactly sure how to do this, but I assume it is something like:

```
array[];

foreach($friend as $x)
if (isset(Input::get('friend')) {
        array[] = Input::get('friend');

 } 
endforeach
```

Could you provide me with a solution to do this?  Thank you.

EDIT:

This is what I have in the controller:

```
public function describe_favorite() {

            $fan = Fan::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $fan->favorite_venue = Input::get('venue');
            $fan->favorite_experience = Input::get('experience');

            $friends_checked = Input::get('friend[]');

            print_r($friends_checked);

            if(is_array($friends_checked))
            {
             $fan->experience_friends = 5;
            }

            $fan->save();


            return Redirect::to('fans/home');

        }
```

It is not going through the "if" loop.  How do I see the output of the print_r to see what's in the $friends_checked variable?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If checkboxes are related then you should use [] in the name attribute.

```
@foreach ($friends as $friend)
<input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="friend[]" id="{{$friend}}" value="{{$friend}}">
@endforeach


$friends_checked = Input::get('friend');
if(is_array($friends_checked))
{
   // do stuff with checked friends
}
```

Comment: Try to see print_r($friends_checked) what it really contains.

Comment: How do I print this variable from the Controller so I can see it?

Comment: just type this in your controller: print_r($friends_checked);

Comment: But then where does it appear??  I can't see it when I do that.

Comment: Please let me know?  I really am not sure how to visualize this.

Comment: print_r() would execute before even rendering your views, so it should be at the beginning of your response document. (view-source at the top). Otherwise you can always pass the `$friends_checked` variable to the view as you would normally do and print it out there. If you find that that variable is empty, you should double-check your client-sidde code where the form resides to make sure that the data is passed to the server at all.

Comment: doing print_r($permissions), where $permissions equivalents name="permissions[]" in my case, only shows value 1 for any number of checkboxes checked. Could you suggest please?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by adding the input name (in your case, "friends[]") to `$fillable` in the relevant model.

Answer (score 1):

The array friend must have a key . If there is $friend->id you could try something like this.

```
 @foreach ($friends as $friend)
  <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="friend[{{$friend->id}}]" id="{{$friend}}">
 @endforeach
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if using a for loop in the controller!

Answer (score 0):

Using name="friend[]" in the form field creates an array named friend that is passed to the server, as opposed to name="friend" which passes a string value to the server.