# Laravel RESTful edit screen with multiple tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have 3 tables for storing business details. The main table and a phone numbers table, as a business can have any number of phone numbers attached to it.

Table 1 - Business listing
Table 2 - Business phone numbers
Table 3 - Links table 1 to table 2 as shown here

```
1   id                  int(11) No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  
2   listings_id         int(11) No  None        
3   listingsphone_id    int(11) No  None        
4   created_at          timestamp           
5   updated_at          timestamp
```

My controller extracts the data from the database and passes it to the view

```
public function edit($id)
{
    // get the listing
    $listing = DB::table('listings')
        ->where('listings.id', '=', $id)
        ->first();

    $listingphone = DB::table('listings')
        ->leftjoin('listings_listingsphone_rel', 'listings.id', '=', 'listings_listingsphone_rel.listings_id')
        ->leftjoin('listingsphone', 'listings_listingsphone_rel.listingsphone_id', '=', 'listingsphone.id')
        ->where('listings.id', '=', $id)
        ->get();

    // show the edit form and pass the listing
    return View::make('admin.listings.edit')
        ->with('listing', $listing)
        ->with('listingphone', $listingphone);
}
```

Blade then needs to create multiple Input rows in the form for outputting to the screen, one for each row that exists.

```
{{ Form::model($listing, array('route' => array('admin.listings.update', $listing->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('listingname', 'Company Name') }}
    {{ Form::text('listingname', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>


@foreach($listingphone as $key => $value)
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('phone', 'Phone number') }}
    {{ Form::text('phone', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>
@endforeach

{{ Form::submit('Edit the Listing!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

The problem with the code is, it will generate for me multiple Input lines with the same Name and ID

```
<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input class="form-control" name="phone" type="text" id="phone">

<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input class="form-control" name="phone" type="text" id="phone">
```

I obviously need to store that data in the controller with code such as this (psuedo code):-

```
    // store
        $listing = Listing::find($id);
        $listing->listings_company        = Input::get('listings_company'); 

        $listing->save();


        // store
        $listingphone = ListingPhone::find($id);

        foreach ($listingphone as $key => $value)
        {
            $listingphone->listings_phone        = Input::get('phone['$key']'); 
            $listingphone->save();
        }
```

How should I be handling this type of setup within Blade/the controller?

Comment: Just use an array for the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the problem you are having the text form fields is the same kind of issue that you need to deal with when you have a checkbox. You have multiple fields with the same name that needs to be referenced anyway.

For that you need to use brackets on the form field name.

You can see a similar example related to checkboxes here:

[How to get the values for a series of checkboxes in Laravel 4 controller (if checked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235910/how-to-get-the-values-for-a-series-of-checkboxes-in-laravel-4-controller-if-che)