# Getting values from checkboxes in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, laravel-5

I'm working on a quote request form on my site and need some help with functionality. I'm trying to get the values from a set of checkboxes that I passed to the view; like so:

**Controller (getQuote)**

```
public function getQuote()
    {

      $services = array(
        'Accept donations',
        'Update website on your own',
        'E-Commerce',
        ...
      );

        return view('pages.quote')->withServices($services);

    }
```

**Controller (postQuote)**

```
public function postQuote(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, [
        'services' => 'required|array',
        ...
      ]);


      $data = array(
        'services' => $request->service,
        ...
      );

      $data['services_checked'] = Input::get('service');
      if(is_array($services_checked))
      {
      }

      Mail::send('emails.quote', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('hi@sogenius.io');
        $message->subject('New quote request for ' .  $data['firstname'] . ' ' . $data['lastname']);

      });

      return redirect()->back()->with('message', "Thanks, your quote request has been sent");

    }
```

**View**

I then loop through the values in the passed array and display it to the user.

```
<article class="col-md-12 text-left services bx1-margin">
                {{ Form::label('services', "Please check all the functionality you would like to see in your new website:") }}

                {{-- <label for="services">Please check all the functionality you would like to see in your new website.</label> --}}
                <ul>
                @foreach ($services as $servicesid => $service)
                  <li>
                    {{-- {{ Form::checkbox('agree', 1, true) }} --}}
                    <input id="{{$servicesid}}" value="{{$servicesid}}" name="service[{{$servicesid}}]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input form-check-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-description">{{$service}}</span>
                    {{-- <input id="s-{{$servicesid}}" name="services" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input form-check-input"> --}}


                  </li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
              </article>
```

When the user submits the form, how do I go about receiving the checked checkboxes?

**Research**

I saw this post here:[How to get the values for a series of checkboxes in Laravel 4 controller (if checked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235910/how-to-get-the-values-for-a-series-of-checkboxes-in-laravel-4-controller-if-che) I saw a post her [(stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235910/how-to-get-the-values-for-a-series-of-checkboxes-in-laravel-4-controller-if-che) and it explains a setting the value to `array[]`, I'm just not quite sure about implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `input` for type `checkbox` using the same name as `services[]` in your html form

```
<input id="{{$servicesid}}" value="{{$servicesid}}" name="service[]" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input form-check-input">
```

So when you submit, just check the variable `$request->service` in your `postQuote` method. It should contains the array variable with all checked inputs submitted.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try this out in a few and report back.

Comment: So I suppressed all the other code and ran 'dd($data['service']);' and voila. Thanks @h44f33z